# Angular UI-Utils + highlight filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have treeview structure in which I have provided search facility.Now I want to provide highlight the search word facility.To get the highlight word functionality I have used angular's ui-utils in which highlight filter is there.But highlight filter only highlights single word.

Like my string is **"I am Test one"** and if I search "**I am**" then it will highlight it. but now I want to highlight **"I Test"** at this time highlight stops working. I want multiple word highlight feature.

Does any one faced this situation? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own `filter` based off Angular UI's Highlight that splits the search query up on spaces. For example,

```
YOUR_MODULE.filter('hightlightWords', function () {
  return function (text, search) {
    if (text && (search || angular.isNumber(search))) {
      text = text.toString();
      search = search.toString();

      angular.forEach(search.split(/\s+/), function(search_part) {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(search_part, 'gi'), '<span class="ui-match">$&</span>');
      });
    }
    return text;
  };
});
```

You can also change the `"ui-match"`to your own highlighting class if you wish.